# How to deploy contract from deployed contract in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to make a contract with function that will deploy other contract while it called.
Is it possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a contract that deploys contracts.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this Test contract.

```
contract Test{
    address public owner=msg.sender;
    // since this contract is deployed by another contract, that contract will be the owner of 
    function setOwner(address _owner) public {
        require(msg.sender==owner,"not owner");
        owner=_owner;
    }
}
```

Write a Deployer contract. pass the bytecode of above contract to the `deploy` function. to get the bytecode call `getByteCode()` and copy the bytecode from Remix

```
contract Deployer{
    // we need bytecode to deploy a contract
    function deploy(bytes memory _bytecode) external payable returns (address addr){
        assembly{
            // we cannot access to msg.value here. we use `callvalue()`
            // when code is loaded first 32 bytes encodes the length of the code. actual code starts after 32 bytes. 0x20=32 in hexadecimal
            // the size of the code is stored in the first 32 bytes 
            addr := create(callvalue(), add(_bytecode,0x20),mload(_bytecode))
            // we get the address and load contract using address in remix
        }
        // zero address means that there was an error creating the code
        require(addr !=address(0),'deploy failed');
    }

   function getByteCode() external pure returns (bytes memory){
      bytes memory bytecode=type(Test).creationCode;
      return bytecode;
}
}
```